# Checkbox value reversed in setState

Tags: reactjs

I need to change state of a component based on checkbox, there is a strange problem, the value in setState is the inverse of the value of event.target.checked.

Based on code above:

If .target.checked === true =>  this.setState set { [event.target.id]: false

If .target.checked === false =>  this.setState set { [event.target.id]: true

```
handleChange(event) {
    if ( event.target.getAttribute('type') == "text"){
        this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
    }else if ( event.target.getAttribute('type') == "checkbox") {
        this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.checked });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem is the async nature of setState, now I use the new state whit a callback and all works fine.

```
this.setState({ [fieldId]: fieldValue }, () => { console.log(this.state); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add a prefix `!` to `event.target.checked` to invert it's value

```
this.setState({ [event.target.id]: !event.target.checked });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the opposite of the previous value. Try this

```
handleChange(event) {
    if ( event.target.getAttribute('type') == "text"){
        this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
    }else if ( event.target.getAttribute('type') == "checkbox") {
        this.setState({ [event.target.id]: !event.target.checked });
    }
}
```

I added an exclamation mark before event.target.checked to indicate "Not" the previous value.